# Extending Controller for common functionalities

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP project and I realized a lot of my controllers have pretty much the same code. I decided I should try making sort of a "BaseController" and having the other controllers extend that... something like this:

```
class BaseController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'RequestHandler'
    );

    public function get($param = "all", $value = "") {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        if($param == "all") {
            $data = $this->Base->find('all');
        }  elseif ($param == "id") {
            $data = $this->Base->findById($value);
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

But at this point I got lost. I do **not** want to have a Base database table and model... I just want something so that don't have to write pretty much the same `get()` method a dozen times... and lets say I make a controller "FooController" that extends this controller... how do I make it so that `get()` now interacts with the Foo model/table?

I assume there is a Cake way of doing this rather than having tons of duplicate code... but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Hi @mcgowan.b, I'm looking in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) for components. I'm not seeing a way that I can work with the database for various models with it, am I missing something?

Comment: The manual says `Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers` which is what you are looking to achieve, common functionality available across all controllers. [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html)

Comment: @mcgowan.b, yes, but I am not talking about just any logic, I'm wanting to have one piece of code that will work with various model's table actions (select, update, delete..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all');` should do the trick http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#268-276.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd want to replace `Base` with the Foo model, I personal would pass the model name as an argument:

```
public function get($param = 'all', $value = '', $model = 'Foo')
{
    $this->layout = 'ajax';

    if($param == 'all') {
        $data = $this->{$model}->find('all');
    } elseif ($param == 'id') {
        $data = $this->{$model}->findById($value);
    }
}
```

Not familiar enough with cake to give a better solution, might not hurt to do some checking on model existence before calling find either.

If this is way off per CakePHP methodology, please excuse me.

Comment: While I can see how this could work, it seems it would still require me to have all of these functions within the `Foo` controller (and other controllers) that just call the related function above.

Comment: I see, so it seems you'd need an extendable model first , then.  I guess when I seen 'Base' I figured Foo model would already be extending that model which provides the findBy functions